# "Hello World" not work for rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

I am new to rabbitmq, but for some (unknown) reason, the "hello
world" program does not work for me.
The send.py and receive.py are simply copied and pasted from the
tutorial page:

http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html

rabbitmq is installed using "yum" on a RHEL 6. Python version is 2.6.
I started the server using

```
$ service rabbitmq-server start
```

and it prints "SUCCESS".

There is no error or warning messages by running send.py and
receive.py:

```
$ python send.py
 [x] Sent 'Hello World!'

$ python receive.py
 [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C
```

Then it never prints "Hello World!".

What's wrong with it?

Comment: hate to state the obvious here, but check that both the send and receive code are connecting to the same server, that the queue names and settings for the queue are the same.  If this is the case you could try enabling the management plugin and view the queue through a browser.  You will see the queue be created and then that there are messages on the queue, if it is working properly.

Comment: This code was running on a VM. I am not sure what was happening as the VM looks like a blackbox for me. But I have tested on another machine (real, not virtual) and it works! Anyone knows what could be the possible reason that the "hello world" code does not work on a VM?

Comment: The code and the MQ were all running on the VM?

Comment: Yes. After running rabbitmqctl list_connections. We see that these messages are blocked because of "resource". Is it duo to a memory or disk alarm? What could block the messages?

Comment: Can you include the output of rabbitmqctl report.  Also have you enabled the management plugin? if not you should, then you can see all the detail through a browser.

Answer (score 12):

First enable the management console

```
sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

Then open the browser

```
http://localhost:55672
```

Login with: guest/guest

In my case it was the memory ( under 2 Giga ) and the message "The disk free space alarm for this node has gone off. It will block incoming network traffic until the amount of free space exceeds the limit."

Edit the file `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config` as follows:

```
 [
    {rabbit, [{disk_free_limit, {mem_relative, 0.1}}]}
 ]
```

Now restart rabbit service:

```
service rabbitmq-server stop
service rabbitmq-server start
```

Comment: Thanks! By running sudo rabbitmqctl status I got this:

     {disk_free_limit,8335626240},
     {disk_free,3692666880},

and indeed it's the disk free (RabbitMQ wants 8.3 GB but I only had 3.6 GB).

How do I change the disk free limit ?

Comment: +1 for the edit, it helped a lot. At first, I thought that it's misspelled JSON, but as it turned out, it's not, and the commas and the dot at the end are required. Thanks.

Comment: I don't find /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config exists, can I manually create that file and what should the initial content of the file be?

Comment: check this out: http://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html, I could create it if it's not there. What OS version are you using?

Comment: For newer versions of rabbitmq the port is 15672 instead of 55672

Answer (score 0):

You have to start `Rabbit MQ Serever`. In windows file name: `RabbitMQ Service - start`. You can use this code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;

public class NewTaskController implements Runnable {
    private final String message;

     private static final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "test";

     private static final String ROUTING_KEY = "test";

     public NewTaskController(final String message) {
         this.message = message;
     }

     @Override
     public void run() {

        //getting data from application.properties
         //for the rabbit_mq configuration

         ResourceBundle mRB = ResourceBundle.getBundle("application");


         System.out.println("*****NewTaskController************"+mRB.getString("rabbitmq.port"));
        String rabbitmq_username = mRB.getString("rabbitmq.username");
        String rabbitmq_password = mRB.getString("rabbitmq.password");
                String rabbitmq_hostname = mRB.getString("rabbitmq.hostname");
                        int rabbitmq_port = Integer.parseInt(mRB.getString("rabbitmq.port"));
     ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
     factory.setUsername(rabbitmq_username);
     factory.setPassword(rabbitmq_password);
     factory.setHost(rabbitmq_hostname);
     factory.setPort(rabbitmq_port);
     Connection conn;
     try {
     conn = factory.newConnection();
     Channel channel = conn.createChannel();

     channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "direct", true);
     String queueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();
     System.out.println(queueName);
     channel.queueBind(queueName, EXCHANGE_NAME, ROUTING_KEY);
     System.out.println("Producing message: " + message + " in thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
     channel.basicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, ROUTING_KEY, null, message.getBytes());

     try {
        channel.close();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     conn.close();
     } catch (IOException | TimeoutException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
}

application.properties file

rabbitmq.username=guest
rabbitmq.password=guest
rabbitmq.hostname=localhost
rabbitmq.port=5672
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue on Windows os with C# dotnet.

I solved the issue by changing the project directory. It was located on D drive.

I moved it to C drive and it's done!